# Difference between sports and sporting

Tags: difference

What is the difference between **sports** and **sporting** when both are used to modify noun. We say

> Sports shoes, sports car

But cannot use **sporting** here

> Sporting country

We cannot say **sports country**

Comment: Neither ***sports country*** nor ***sporting country*** sound particularly idiomatic to me, but according to Google Books they both occur. I must admit ***a sporting country*** makes me think of *a country having the attribute **sporting = fair and generous** (in behaviour or treatment of others).* Whatever - the question is based on the false premise that [***a sports country***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+sports+country%22) isn't a valid construction. I'd also just add that *a pair of **sporting** shoes* sounds really weird to me, so that looks like another false premise.

Comment: I also say that sporting shoes is wrong

Comment: have you looked in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

"Sporting" generally means something different from "sports".  I'm afraid this is another one of those cases where the *expected* usage of an English word can be different from its *actual* usage.  "Sporting" is an adjective:

> **[sporting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sporting)** (adj):
>   1. connected with or interested in sports. *"a major sporting event"*
>   2. fair and generous in one's behavior or treatment of others, especially in a game or contest. *"it was not very sporting of Smith to hit Gonzales with that pitch"*

while "sports" is a noun:

> **[sports](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sport)** (n): 1.1 An occasion on which people compete in various athletic activities. *"I won the 200 metres in the school sports"*

Unfortunately the usage is mostly based on idiom.  "Sports" can be used in *compound nouns* to mean "related to sports":

> [7 Ways to Level-Up Your **Sports** Event Management](https://www.socialtables.com/blog/event-planning/sports-event-management/)

However this title could have instead used "sporting":

> [See Where the Olympics Rank on Our List of Top 10 **Sporting** Events](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/travel/top-10/sporting-events/)

To complicate this, "sport" (singular) is also used in compound nouns:

> Alonzo and Jeff went to the mall to buy **sport/sports** shoes for school.

Which to use ("sport", "sports", and "sporting") seems to vary between different nouns, different expressions, and even different dialects.  For example, "sports country" makes sense as the name of a television or radio show:

> Hey y'all, you're watching **Sports Country** on ESPN!

but not in conversation (although it does seem to be used).  Instead "sporting nation" seems to be used (although this may be an Indian expression):

> [Realizing The Dream Of A **Sporting** Nation](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/273523)

I apologize that I'm answering your question by providing examples rather than rules, but again, the usage here seems to be based on idiom rather than grammar.  It seems you might just have to repeat what you hear native speakers say.

Note: In the definition above you'll see that "sporting" has a different meaning, related to the idea of *fair play* in sports.  If you choose to use "sporting" you have to be careful not to confuse the meanings.  For example, a "sporting event" is one in which sports occur, but a "sporting gentleman" is one who believes in giving his opponent a fair chance to win -- or, in some cases, a man who likes to gamble.